# Queryset Django

Tags: json, django, api

Here is my view in Django:

```
class QuerySet1(generics.ListAPIView):
    """Количество приемов у каждого врача"""
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny, ]

    def get_queryset(self):
        app_num = Appointment.objects.values('record__doctor').annotate(amount=Count("id"))
        app_num = list(app_num)
        print(app_num)
        return app_num
    serializer_class = QuerySet1Serializer
```

output is:

```
[{'record__doctor': 1, 'amount': 1}, {'record__doctor': 4, 'amount': 5}, {'record__doctor': 5, 'amount': 2}]
```

and this is serializer:

```
class QuerySet1Serializer(serializers.Serializer):
    amount = serializers.IntegerField()
    doctor = serializers.CharField(source='record__doctor')

    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        fields = ("amount", "doctor")
```

When I run code it gives me next error

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

Help please! How can I solve it? Thanks

Comment: the **`app_num`** is `dict` rather than a **`QuerySet`** object

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you could `annotate` the grouped value, and then extract your desired values out

```
from django.db.models import F

qs = Appointment.objects.values('record__doctor').annotate(
       amount=Count("id"), doctor=F('record__doctor')
       ).values('amount', 'doctor')
         
# list(qs) would yield as follows, no need to use source
[{'doctor': 1, 'amount': 1}, {'doctor': 4, 'amount': 5}, {'doctor': 5, 'amount': 2}]


# serializer
class QuerySet1Serializer(serializers.Serializer):
    amount = serializers.IntegerField()
    doctor = serializers.CharField(source='record__doctor')

# view
class MylistView(generics.ListAPIView):
    """Количество приемов у каждого врача"""
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny, ]

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Appointment.objects.values('record__doctor').annotate(
             amount=Count("id"), doctor=F('record__doctor')
             ).values('amount', 'doctor')
        return qs
    serializer_class = QuerySet1Serializer
```

Comment: I was a bit incorrect in my explanation, output is what I got after print(app_num)

Comment: @DaryaShipitcyna you have a `serilaizer`  with  `class Meta ` points to a model, while you don't need the model for your serialization

Comment: @DaryaShipitcyna delete `Meta model=...,fields=(...)` options,no use

Comment: return the `Queryset` object, not list, just return `qs`, still not working?

Comment: what errors reported back? I thought this would work

Comment: 'F' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: @DaryaShipitcyna Ok, my bad, one missing parenthesis after `F` value, and an extra parenthesis in the end